# Designs for a Board Breaker / Board Holder?

Tags: tae-kwon-do, power, breaking-boards

Does anyone have designs to build your own DIY board breaker/board holder for power breaking?

Answer (score 6):

Around the beginning of 2012, I spent some time online trying to locate a freely available design for a martial arts board holder. At the time there was nothing available*. So after taking some inspiration from a few commercially available compact designs (see: http://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=board+holder+martial+arts) I came up with my own.

[In this HowTo](http://www.fusionmartialarts.com.au/blog/?p=57), I show you how to make a collapsible martial arts board holder entirely out of broken Martial Arts boards. It can be easily attached to a heavy punching bag, held by a partner or supported against/hung on a wall. (see: http://www.fusionmartialarts.com.au/blog/?p=57 )

As a pure coolness bonus, this design is made entirely from previously broken martial arts boards (plus glue, screws, bungie and some fabric). In the posting is a demonstration of a power break using 4 UMAB boards (Yellow, Green, Brown and Black) of approx 5.5 boards.

*- For reference, I recently found another HowTo detailing the build process of a non-collapsible board holder that has some very nice design ideas: http://www.karate.gregoryzone.org/?p=219. It is worthwhile to have a look at this design to compare and contrast.

Comment: Nice :) From your article: *`Matching the two sides of a board from a pile of halves can be a challenge`* - the solution is to break more boards, thus producing more options :) Moar!!

Comment: @slugster: THAT is funny (and so very true)!

Comment: Can you quote and repost some of the information here to prevent link rot? I'm sure there are some people who would appreciate the knowledge but not necessarily want to click through a bunch of links whereas this question here would serve the purpose of presenting such information.

Comment: I've been meaning to post it in my reply for a while now, but the way StackExchange does the posts, it'll take me a while to get the images inline. Where as if I could just copy and paste from the Wordpress... I'll get it post here, eventually!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a design I created in the 1990s using CAD software. I have used it for decades to break 1x12 common pine boards in stacks of 1 to 10.

Enjoy,
-Peter
[http://world.std.com/~pce/holder1a.ps](http://world.std.com/%7Epce/holder1a.ps)